# Link errors with PHP pagination class and AJAX/JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pagination

On my search results page, a user can modify his search results with buttons on the left. these buttons use jquery to update the results in a div. however, when the results are re-called with jquery and echoed back into the div, the links for NEXT PAGE, LAST PAGE, etc do not work properly. This is the pagination class I'm using:

```
  class pagination
  {
    var $page = 1; // Current Page
    var $perPage = 10; // Items on each page, defaulted to 10
    var $showFirstAndLast = false; // if you would like the first and last page options.

    function generate($array, $perPage = 10)
    {
      // Assign the items per page variable
      if (!empty($perPage))
        $this->perPage = $perPage;

      // Assign the page variable
      if (!empty($_GET['page'])) {
        $this->page = $_GET['page']; // using the get method
      } else {
        $this->page = 1; // if we don't have a page number then assume we are on the first page
      }

      // Take the length of the array
      $this->length = count($array);

      // Get the number of pages
      $this->pages = ceil($this->length / $this->perPage);

      // Calculate the starting point 
      $this->start  = ceil(($this->page - 1) * $this->perPage);

      // Return the part of the array we have requested
      return array_slice($array, $this->start, $this->perPage);
    }

    function links()
    {
      // Initiate the links array
      $plinks = array();
      $links = array();
      $slinks = array();

      // Concatenate the get variables to add to the page numbering string
      if (count($_GET)) {
        $queryURL = '';
        foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
          if ($key != 'page') {
            $queryURL .= '&'.$key.'='.$value;
          }
        }
      }

      // If we have more then one pages
      if (($this->pages) > 1)
      {
        // Assign the 'previous page' link into the array if we are not on the first page
        if ($this->page != 1) {
          if ($this->showFirstAndLast) {
            $plinks[] = ' <a href="?page=1'.$queryURL.'">&laquo;&laquo; First </a> ';
          }
          $plinks[] = ' <a href="?page='.($this->page - 1).$queryURL.'">&laquo; Prev</a> ';
        }

        // Assign all the page numbers & links to the array
        for ($j = 1; $j < ($this->pages + 1); $j++) {
          if ($this->page == $j) {
            $links[] = ' <a class="selected">'.$j.'</a> '; // If we are on the same page as the current item
          } else {
            $links[] = ' <a href="?page='.$j.$queryURL.'">'.$j.'</a> '; // add the link to the array
          }
        }

        // Assign the 'next page' if we are not on the last page
        if ($this->page < $this->pages) {
          $slinks[] = ' <a href="?page='.($this->page + 1).$queryURL.'"> Next &raquo; </a> ';
          if ($this->showFirstAndLast) {
            $slinks[] = ' <a href="?page='.($this->pages).$queryURL.'"> Last &raquo;&raquo; </a> ';
          }
        }

        // Push the array into a string using any some glue
        return implode(' ', $plinks).implode($this->implodeBy, $links).implode(' ', $slinks);
      }
      return;
    }
  }
?>
```

If the results are displayed on search.php, and the jqueried modified results are called from search_again.php, the pagination links (NEXT, LAST etc) will follow search.php, and not be updated with search_again.php.

I have tried changing this:

```
$slinks[] = ' <a href="?page='.($this->page + 1).$queryURL.'"> Next &raquo; </a> ';
```

to this:

```
$slinks[] = ' <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.($this->page + 1).$queryURL.'"> Next &raquo; </a> ';
```

and it does somewhat work, however the this links is clicked, instead of being confined to the results div on search.php, it will be loaded in the entire page itself. Does anyone have any experience with this? Thanks

Edit: Here is my JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button").click(function(){
    var miles = $('#miles').val();
    $.ajax({
            url: 'thetestsession.php', //the variable miles is set being $_GET
            data: 'miles=' + miles,    //on this page and set to session 
            type: 'GET',               //variable. miles is variable
                                               //that a user can modify his 
                                               //search with.
            success: function(results) {
                $("#results").html(results); //#results is the div 
                //alert("Ok.");
            }
        });                               //then i load thetestresults.php
    $("#results").load('thetestresults.php'); //this is the page where the re-query
        return false;                     //takes place.
});                                               
});
```

Comment: Added it in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

It might work if you add the ID "#button" to the link tags in your php. I think you forgot it... Correct me if I'm wrong!
greets

Comment: Like `$slinks[] = ' <a href="?page='.($this->page + 1).$queryURL.'#button"> Next &raquo; </a> ';` ? This did not work.

Comment: you have to set the CSS ID Tag:    `$slinks[] = ' <a id="button" href="?page='.($this->page + 1).$queryURL.'"> Next &raquo; </a> ';`